# How to force ListPlot to print the new curve while keeping the old one

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, dynamic, interactive

I would like to create a graph using `ListPlot` which prints new dataset every time   the button is evaluated (based on the value given in `InputField`), by adding the new curve to the one that has been previously plotted, showing multiple curves.

For example: if the button is clicked 5 times, the graph should show 5 curves.

The `ListPlot` I have here does replace the old dataset with the new one (always showing only one curve) every time the value of `InputField` is changed and button is re-evaluated, which is not what I want. How to force `ListPlot` to print the new curve while keeping the old one?

```
 DynamicModule[{inputValue = 0, dataSet = {}}, 
 Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[inputValue]], 
   Button["Plot", dataSet = Table[inputValue + i^j, {i, 5}, {j, 2}]], 
   Spacer[5],
   Dynamic@ListPlot[dataSet, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}]
   }]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Append` the new data to your `dataSet` each time the button is pressed, rather than simply assigning it a new value:

```
DynamicModule[
 {inputValue = 0, dataSet = {}},
 Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[inputValue]],
   Button["Plot", AppendTo[dataSet, Table[inputValue + i^j, {i, 5}, {j, 2}]]],
   Spacer[5],
   Dynamic@ListPlot[dataSet, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}]
 }]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this is exactly what I need :)